# SharePoint 2010 Database Schema Versions Not Responding error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have multiple site collections in one webapplication and each site collection is in its own content DB. Now when I browse to one of the site collection, it gives me HTTP 404 not found error. And When I dig deeper what's causing it, I found below error in "Manage content Database settings" section of central admin:-

Database Schema Versions Not Responding.

Other site collections in that webapplication are fine and rendering without any issue.Any idea how to fix this "Schema version issue" for that one site collection?

Thanks

Comment: did you check the DB on the Database Server, is it up and running( i mean not offline or read only mode or recovery Mode)?

Comment: Compare the content database schema for that site collection against your other content databases via the Manage Content Databases in the Central Administration. If it differs then you may want to attempt to upgrade the schema using powershell (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813(v=office.15).aspx).  Of course, you should have a back up and perhaps test the behaviors in a different environment first.

Comment: @Waqas: database is in ready state and not set to redonly

Comment: @Erik: Content DB schema is not displayed at all instead i see "Not Responding" message under "Database Schema Versions". But for other working sites it displays the schema versions. So I don't think upgrade schema works.

Comment: problem at the db server ends. try to detach & reattach at sharepoint web application....if it is production then do it off hours becuse this will cause the outage

Comment: I agree with @WaqasSarwarMCSE here without having any further information.  I do find it odd that you would have one single content database where this is happening. Did any SharePoint updates get applied manually or via Windows Updates?  I had a schema version mismatch recently and it appeared to be due to a Windows Update.  The content database upgrade fixed it in our environment but content had always been rendering for users.